# Unable to Run psql in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: postgresql

I have just installed postgreSQL and have set up the user postgres and its password. In the psql Shell I am able to login as normal however I can't login in Windows Command Prompt. When I run the psql command it asks for `Password for user username` for which I don't know the password.

I have tried running `dropuser username` in the psql shell however this doesn't make a difference. When I use psql -u postgres to login and run `postgres=# \du`, the other role doesn't appear:

```
                                  List of roles
Role name |                         Attributes                         | 
Member 
of
----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

Comment: Pass the Postgres user you know the password for `psql -U someuser ...`

Comment: This allows me to login but will I have to do this every time rather than just `psql`

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the default behaviour that chooses the current Windows' user name as the login for the database, you can [define](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10) the [environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) `PGUSER` that contains the user you want to use by default.

Once that is defined and you type `psql` it assumes *that* user as the default.

Related: [How do I specify a password to psql non-interactively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127)